# Gson how to deserialise null object property

Tags: java, json, gson

I have some json, with a sequence of entries which look like this (I've simplified it tofocus on relevant issue which is why it looks a little redundant):

> {"name":"ISPC Seychelles","company":{"name":"ISPC
>   Seychelles","id":3427640}}

sometimes however the company property is set to null:

> {"name":"Westin Miyako Kyoto", "company":null}

I have defined my classes like this (sorry for the public access modifiers, will change these when I get this bit of code working :)) :

```
class Entry {
  public String name=;
  public Company company;
  public String toString() {
      return  name + ";" + company;
  }
}

class Company {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public String toString() {
        return "Company: " + name;
    }
}
```

In my code, I try to use gson to deserialise the JSON contained in the variable called output:

```
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reply reply = gson.fromJson(output, Reply.class); 
    Entry[] entries = reply.entries;
    for (int i=0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(entries[i]+ "\n") ;
    }
}
```

This works fine when the company element is populated as in the first example in the JSON:

> ISPC Seychelles;Company: ISPC Seychelles

However, if the element is not populated as in the second example, I get the following output:

> Westin Miyako Kyoto; null

What I would like is the following output:

> Westin Miyako Kyoto; Company: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `toString()` representation of `Company` is controlled by the `Company` object, so there is no way you can get the representation you want if the `Company` object is null. The only way to do it is to have something like the following in your `Entry` class' `toString()`:

```
class Entry {
  ...
  ...

    public String toString() {
        return  name + "; " + (company != null ? company : "Company: null");
    }
}
```